# How to find the limit of a function inside a function?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I am taking a basic calculus class and my professor never explained this but I have this question on the homework:

Suppose $\lim \limits_{x \to b} f(x) = 7$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to b} g(x) = −3$

Find $\lim \limits_{x\to b}(f(x)+g(x))$

How do you solve a problem like this?

Comment: Please use MathJax for readability. Click edit on Siong Thye Goh's answer to see how. (or, now, click edit on your question)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax references. Try to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following result:

If $\lim \limits_{x \to b} f(x) $ and $\lim \limits_{x \to b} g(x) $ exist, then

$$\lim_{x \to b} (f(x) + g(x)) = \lim_{x \to b}f(x) + \lim_{x \to b} g(x) $$

Sum of limit is the limit of the sum.

You might want to read up more on [what operations can you perform with limits.](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitsProperties.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the correction =)

Comment: You're welcome :p.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the function, f, is "continuous" then, from the **definition** of "continuous", $\lim_{x\to b} f(g(x))= f(\lim_{x\to b}g(x))$.

But the example you give is **not** a "function inside a function"- you have a linear combination of two functions.  One of the very first "laws of limits" you should have learned is ""$\lim_{x\to b} (f(x)+ g(x))= \lim_{x\to b} f(x)+ \lim_{x\to b} g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_f,\delta_g>0$ such that
$|x-b|\leq \delta_f$ implies $|f(x)-7|<\epsilon/2$ and
$|x-b|\leq \delta_g$ implies $|g(x)+3|<\epsilon/2$.
It follows that for all $x$ such that $|x-b|\leq \min\{\delta_f,\delta_g\}$, we have 
$$|f(x)+g(x)-4|\leq |f(x)-7|+|g(x)+3|\leq \epsilon$$
which implies $\lim_{x\to b}(f(x)+g(x))=4$